# How to display collection data in grid ui admin?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, admin, collection, ui

I create a controller to get data from the database as code below.

The query in controller:

```
$orderCollection = $this->_salesOrderCollectionFactory->create()
            ->addFieldToFilter(
                ['status','status','status'],
                [
                    ['eq' => 'delivering'],
                    ['eq' => 'refunded_cancel'],
                    ['eq' => 'refund_kpt_failed']
                ]
            )
            ->addAttributeToSelect('delivery_flightnumber')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('delivery_origin')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('delivery_destination')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('delivery_departure');
        $orderCollection->getSelect()
            ->columns('COUNT(*) AS total_order')
            ->columns('SUM(total_item_count) as total_item')
            ->columns('SUM(base_subtotal) as subtotal')
            ->columns('SUM(base_grand_total) as total')
            ->columns('SUM(base_discount_amount) as discount')
            ->columns('SUM(base_total_refunded) as refunded')
            ->group('delivery_flightnumber')
            ->group('delivery_departure')
            ->order('delivery_departure DESC');
```

[image]

So, I create a model to display the data in the grid.
MyModule\Model\ResourceModel\Report.php

```
protected function _construct()
    {
        // TODO: Implement _construct() method.
        $this->_init('sales_order', 'entity_id');
    }
```

I created MyModule\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection.php

```
protected $_idFieldName = 'entity_id';
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'salereports_report_collection';
    protected $_eventObject = 'report_collection';

    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('MyModule\Model\Report', 'MyModule\Model\ResourceModel\Report');
    }

    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub

        $this->addFieldToFilter(
            ['status','status','status'],
            [
                ['eq' => 'delivering'],
                ['eq' => 'refunded_cancel'],
                ['eq' => 'refund_kpt_failed']
            ]
        )
            ->addAttributeToSelect('delivery_flightnumber')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('delivery_origin')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('delivery_destination')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('delivery_departure');
        $this->getSelect()
            ->columns('COUNT(*) AS total_order')
            ->columns('SUM(total_item_count) as total_item')
            ->columns('SUM(base_subtotal) as subtotal')
            ->columns('SUM(base_grand_total) as total')
            ->columns('SUM(base_discount_amount) as discount')
            ->columns('SUM(base_total_refunded) as refunded')
            ->group('delivery_flightnumber')
            ->group('delivery_departure')
            ->order('delivery_departure DESC');

$saleOrderData = $orderCollection->getData();

        $result = [];

        $result[] = [
            'Date time',
            'Name',
            'Orders',
            'Items',
            'Subtotal',
            'Discount',
            'Total',
            'Refunded',
            'Revenue',
        ];

        foreach ($saleOrderData as $saleOrder) {
            $revenue = $saleOrder['total'] - $saleOrder['refunded'];
            $delivery = $saleOrder['delivery_origin'].'-'.$saleOrder['delivery_destination'];

            $result[] = [
                $saleOrder['delivery_departure'],
                $delivery,
                $saleOrder['total_order'],
                $saleOrder['total_item'],
                $saleOrder['subtotal'],
                $saleOrder['discount'],
                $saleOrder['total'],
                $saleOrder['refunded'],
                $revenue,
            ];
        }
        
        return $result;
    }
```

So I create `view\adminhtml\ui_component\mymodule_report_listing.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <!-- main part of the grid -->
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">salereports_report_listing.salereports_report_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">salereports_report_listing.salereports_report_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <!-- define where to find the columns -->
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">salereport_report_columns</item>

        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="report" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">report</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Show report</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/report/*</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>

    <!-- define the data_source (must be the same than in argument/item/provider and argument/js_config/deps -->
    <dataSource name="salereports_report_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">salereports_report_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <columns name="spinner_columns">
        <column name="delivery_flightnumber">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Flight Number</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="delivery_departure" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Date time</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="delivery_name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="total_order">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Orders</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="total_item">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Items</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="subtotal">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Subtotal</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="discount">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Discount</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="total">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Total</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="refunded">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Refunded</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="Revenue">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Revenue</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

To display the data from the query. But it can not run to `_initselect function` and it can't display the column name in query data. It can display the data with the column name in the `sales_order` table.

it displays the data with the column_name of the sales_order table. it not right.
[image]

How to display the data from the query model or controller in grid listing?

Please help me,

Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you please add the code for the listing.xml file?

Comment: Hi @Shankar I have just pust the code for the listing xml. My code can't run to _initSelect. Please help me. Thanks!